# how to render with ggplot2 generated images to plotly using ggplotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

As you can see in the following code i tried to build an R shiny app useful for dynamically generating plots .Then i decided in the second code to take advantage of the benefits of the plotly plotting options by tranforming them to plotly images.The problem is that i could get only one piece of plots (the right side):

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(patchwork)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  
  #- header with sidebar configurations
  header = dashboardHeader(

  ),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
  
    sidebarMenu(
      
    
          
      
    )
  ),
  
  #- body (center)
  
  body <- dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      tabBox(
        
        # The id lets us use input$tabset1 on the server to find the current tab
        id = "tabset1",height = 750,width=20,
        
        
        tabPanel("PCM Data",withSpinner(dataTableOutput(outputId = "table"))),
        tabPanel("Trend Presentation",uiOutput('choose_parameter'),uiOutput("plots"),downloadButton('report'))
      
        
        
        
        
      )
    )
    
  )
)





server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
    
    output$choose_parameter <- renderUI({selectizeInput(inputId = "Parmeter", 
                                                        label = "Choose Parameter",
                                                        choices = names(mpg),  multiple=T)})
    
      
      spa<-reactive({req(input$Parmeter)
        spa<-input$Parmeter})
      req(mpg)
      dt <- mpg
      myplotdata<-reactive({dt %>% select("manufacturer",intersect(spa(), names(dt)))})
      
      
    
    
    
    output$table <- renderDataTable({
     mpg
      
    },
    
    options = list(scrollX = TRUE))
    
    observe({
      
      req(input$Parmeter)
      req(myplotdata())
  
      lapply(input$Parmeter, function(par){
      
          p1<-ggplot(myplotdata(), aes(x ="manufacturer",y = par,group=1)) +
            geom_point(size=2,colour="#007A9D",shape=4)+
            theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))+
            theme(axis.text.y.left = element_text(color = "#007A9D"),
                  axis.title.y.left  = element_text(color = "#007A9D"))
          
       
            
   
          
        
        
        
        
        if (is.numeric(myplotdata()[[par]]) || is.integer(myplotdata()[[par]])){     
          p2 <- ggplot(myplotdata(), aes_string(y = par)) +
            geom_histogram(binwidth = 2) +
            labs(y = NULL)}
        else{p2<-NULL}
      
        
        
        p3 <-  ggplot(myplotdata()) +
          theme_void() +
          annotate(
            geom = "label",
            x = 0, y = .5,
            label = if (is.numeric(myplotdata()[[par]]) || is.integer(myplotdata()[[par]])){paste(
              "Mean = ", round(mean(myplotdata()[[par]],na.rm=T), 1), "\n",
              "Sigma = ", round(sd(myplotdata()[[par]],na.rm=T), 1),"\n",
              "Min = ", round(min(myplotdata()[[par]],na.rm=T), 1),"\n",
              "Max = ", round(max(myplotdata()[[par]],na.rm=T), 1),"\n",
              "Cp/k = ", round(max(myplotdata()[[par]],na.rm=T), 1)
            )}
            else {
              paste(
                "Mean = ",NA, "\n",
                "Sigma = ",NA,"\n",
                "Min = ", NA,"\n",
                "Max = ", NA,"\n",
                "Cp/k = ", NA 
              )}
            
            ,
            hjust = 0
          )
       
        
        
        
        
        output[[paste("plot", par, sep = "_")]] <- renderPlot({
          p3+p1+p2+ plot_layout(widths = c(1, 3, 1))
        },height = 350,
        width=1800)
        
        
        
      }
      )
      
      
      
    })
    
    output$plots <- renderUI({
      req(input$Parmeter)
      plot_output_list <- lapply(input$Parmeter, function(par) {
        plotname <- paste("plot", par, sep = "_")
        plotOutput(plotname, height = '250px', inline=TRUE)
      })
      
      do.call(tagList, plot_output_list)
      
    })
    
    
    
    
    
   
    
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The second code:

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(patchwork)
library(plotly)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  
  #- header with sidebar configurations
  header = dashboardHeader(

  ),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
  
    sidebarMenu(
      
    
          
      
    )
  ),
  
  #- body (center)
  
  body <- dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      tabBox(
        
        # The id lets us use input$tabset1 on the server to find the current tab
        id = "tabset1",height = 750,width=20,
        
        
        tabPanel("PCM Data",withSpinner(dataTableOutput(outputId = "table"))),
        tabPanel("Trend Presentation",uiOutput('choose_parameter'),uiOutput("plots"),downloadButton('report'))
      
        
        
        
        
      )
    )
    
  )
)





server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
    
    output$choose_parameter <- renderUI({selectizeInput(inputId = "Parmeter", 
                                                        label = "Choose Parameter",
                                                        choices = names(mpg),  multiple=T)})
    
      
      spa<-reactive({req(input$Parmeter)
        spa<-input$Parmeter})
      req(mpg)
      dt <- mpg
      myplotdata<-reactive({dt %>% select("manufacturer",intersect(spa(), names(dt)))})
      
      
    
    
    
    output$table <- renderDataTable({
     mpg
      
    },
    
    options = list(scrollX = TRUE))
    
    observe({
      
      req(input$Parmeter)
      req(myplotdata())
  
      lapply(input$Parmeter, function(par){
      
          p1<-ggplot(myplotdata(), aes(x ="manufacturer",y = par,group=1)) +
            geom_point(size=2,colour="#007A9D",shape=4)+
            theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))+
            theme(axis.text.y.left = element_text(color = "#007A9D"),
                  axis.title.y.left  = element_text(color = "#007A9D"))
          
       
            
   
          
        
        
        
        
        if (is.numeric(myplotdata()[[par]]) || is.integer(myplotdata()[[par]])){     
          p2 <- ggplot(myplotdata(), aes_string(y = par)) +
            geom_histogram(binwidth = 2) +
            labs(y = NULL)}
        else{p2<-NULL}
      
        
        
        p3 <-  ggplot(myplotdata()) +
          theme_void() +
          annotate(
            geom = "label",
            x = 0, y = .5,
            label = if (is.numeric(myplotdata()[[par]]) || is.integer(myplotdata()[[par]])){paste(
              "Mean = ", round(mean(myplotdata()[[par]],na.rm=T), 1), "\n",
              "Sigma = ", round(sd(myplotdata()[[par]],na.rm=T), 1),"\n",
              "Min = ", round(min(myplotdata()[[par]],na.rm=T), 1),"\n",
              "Max = ", round(max(myplotdata()[[par]],na.rm=T), 1),"\n",
              "Cp/k = ", round(max(myplotdata()[[par]],na.rm=T), 1)
            )}
            else {
              paste(
                "Mean = ",NA, "\n",
                "Sigma = ",NA,"\n",
                "Min = ", NA,"\n",
                "Max = ", NA,"\n",
                "Cp/k = ", NA 
              )}
            
            ,
            hjust = 0
          )
       
        
        
        
        
        output[[paste("plot", par, sep = "_")]] <- renderPlotly({
    p<-p3+p1+p2+plot_layout(widths = c(1, 3, 1))
    plotly::ggplotly(p)
        },height = 350,
        width=1800)
        
        
        
      }
      )
      
      
      
    })
    
    output$plots <- renderUI({
      req(input$Parmeter)
      plot_output_list <- lapply(input$Parmeter, function(par) {
        plotname <- paste("plot", par, sep = "_")
        plotOutput(plotname, height = '250px', inline=TRUE)
      })
      
      do.call(tagList, plot_output_list)
      
    })
    
   
    
    
    
   
    
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: In the future, I would advise cleaning up your question and providing a minimally reproducible question, you'll see a lot more feedback quicker. In the meantime, I will tell you that `geom_label` doesn't translate (for lack of a better word) into Plotly. You can create something that mimics you what you store in `p1`, `p2`, and `p3`, but not with `geom_label` => `ggplotly`.  Lastly, `Patchwork` is for `ggplot2`. In `Plotly`, you would typically use `plotly::subplot`.

Comment: @Kat is the question non understandable?.Your said" minimally reproducible" but i see that my code is executable.

Comment: You're right; it's reproducible. That's extremely important and great to see! However, it's not *minimally* reproducible. There is a lot of information that isn't really relevant to the question, tons of white space. It took a while to find what differed between the two applications. I don't mind looking through it, but I think you'll get a lot more feedback and faster feedback when what works and what doesn't (in the code) is easy to identify.